# South an ImageField in Django

Tags: django, django-south

South is a great thing for managing database fields but i don't understand - why on earth it doesn't work with ImageFields?

Here is my situation - i went through official South tutorial like this - my model:

```
from django.db import models


class Knight(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    of_the_round_table = models.BooleanField()
    dances_whenever_able = models.BooleanField()
```

**schemamigration Knights --auto** and **migrate Knights** did well. But then i'm adding a field:

```
photo_of_a_knight = models.ImageField(upload_to='/photos/')
```

**schemamigration --auto** and **migrate Knights** result in a following error:

```
table "_south_new_Knights_knight" already exists
```

I saw some workarounds here but they are not useful for me. Finally i need to delete all tables related to South and my app and migrations will be done well. How do i overcome this?

Comment: I think you forgot to faked the initial migration 0001? `migrate Knights 0001 --fake` and then do normal migrate.

Comment: Please list the generated migration files.  It looks like you may have generated the migration twice.

Comment: 2 Aamir Adnan - fake migration did nothing got the same error. 2 Kevin Stone - there are 3 files in migrations folder: 0001_initial.py, 0002_auto__add_field_knight_photo.py and __init__.py.

Comment: What's the content of `0002_auto__add_field_knight_photo.py` and is the database structure containing the table knight including all columns?